# C# posting data to webserver using POST method issue

Tags: c#

While posting data I am getting issue. The issue is in the & character. I am posting a string which may contain anything. like "`this&this, how are you?`".
But in the above case only "`this`" is sending. String from the character `&` is stripped.

Code I tried:

```
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite.com/import.php");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write("tname=sanam&temail=sanam@" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".com&tbody=" + this.body + "&ttitle=" + this.title);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    retStr = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                //retStr = "POST: " + this.body;

            }
```

Does anybody know how to send anything to the server using C#? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode the free text fields trough

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()
```

IE:

```
streamWriter.Write("tname=sanam&temail=sanam@" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".com&tbody=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.body) + "&ttitle=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.title));
```

Comment: @Sarah - can you not see a *similar* line in your original code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am having this error:
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) F:\D\dotNET things\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\crawler\emailExtractor\post.cs 50 124 emailExtractor

Comment: @Sarah - add reference to System.Web assembly in your project.